Entity Framework Core : AsSplitQuery with complex filters does not return specific navigation properties when using ToListAsync
We have a complex query on an entity called Image. This entity has many navigation properties and we are using AsSplitQuery because there are a lot of images and many tables and AsNoTracking.
The request is built this way:
var query = entity1Repository.Include(x => x.Entity2)
                             .ThenInclude(x => x.Entity3)
                             .Include(x => ...)
                             [...]
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .AsSplitQuery();

if ([condition]) 
{
    query = query.Where(x => ... );
}
if([condition])
{
  // There is this kind of case with order by in the query
  query = query.Where(x => x.Entity2.OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault().Prop == search.Prop.Value); 
}
// [more filters]

// Navigation property value for entity2 exist
var image = await query.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == 1234);

// Navigation property value for entity2 missing for some entity1
var result = await query.ToListAsync(); 

When the request is triggered with ToListAsync(), some navigation property values are missing on some entities (not all).
When using .Single(x => x.Id == ...), then the navigation properties are correctly loaded.
Without AsSplitQuery, the request works fine if not much data is requested, else it times out so we can't remove it.
I'm using EF Core 7.0.20, SQL Server and ASP.NET Core 6.
Entity configuration is working fine, nothing to report here since a year now.
Question: What can be the source of this behaviour?
== EDIT ==
After many try, we found a workaround that seems to work fine ( there is still adaptation to make)
We project the entity to an intermediate class (we called it projection):
public class entityProjection {
   public int entity1Id {get;set;}
   public int entity2Id {get;set;}
   public string entity1Property {get;set;}
   public string entity2Property {get;set;}
   public Entity2PropertyClassProjection entity2ClassProperty {get;set;}
}

Then with the previous query:
query = query.Select(x => new entityProjection(){
  entityId1 = x.Id,
  entityId2 = x.entity2.Id,
  entity1Property = x.property1,
  entity2Property = x.property2,
  // For sub navigation properties
  entity2PropertyClass = new Entity2PropertyClassProjection{ 
    classProp1 = x.entity2.ClassProperty.classProp1,
    classProp2 = x.entity2.ClassProperty.classProp2,
    [...]
  }
});

It simplify the query construction later so good point for this workaround. But it is not an answer as to why ToList() don't give the same result as with Single();

Try AsNoTracking() first, if problem solved, then ChangeTracker contains modified data. Not sure that someone can help you in EF Core debugging SQL analysing.

Also ensure you aren't using pagination with Skip and Take when using a Split Query as this is a limitation of the split approach optimization.

@StevePy, which limitations with Skip, Take? Split queries should work with everything.

I should have clarified, it is dependent on unique ordering. Without that you can get a selection of 50 arbitrary rows for the parent table, and dependents in separate queries associating to not necessarily the same 50 parents. So sorting by something like a status to prioritize Status1 before 2 and taking the top 10 results for instance can bugger up with AsSplitQuery  when there are more than 10 rows with Status 1 without also sorting on something to ensure the rows are in a definitive order. (I.e. Status + CreatedDateTime)

Have you tried upgrading to a newer EF Core version? Note that .NET Core 6 is now out of support and you should upgrade to v8

SvyatoslavDanyliv We have already "AsNoTracking", I forgot to mention it. Edited question to reflect that.
StevePy: No skip and take in the query. But there is different ordering on some property to filter values on navigation properties"Entity2.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateTime).FirstOrDefault()". Added to the question.
Charlieface no upgrading of efCore planned yet, but I will take a look.
